# How to get IP of incoming requests while using ngrok?

Tags: ip, ngrok

I am using ngrok to tunnel 8000 port, on which my django project is running. ngrok prints all incoming requests on the console, I want it to print the IP address of source of incoming requests as well.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can see verbose information about each and every request on ngrok's web interface at http://127.0.0.1:4040

It's not as conventient as having it on the CLI directly but it's a way.